# How to insert data in SQL Server in an Android application

Tags: c#, android, sql, sql-server

In order to insert data into an SQL Server database on an Android application do I simply need to execute a query ? I have the following code :

```
public int SaveUser(User user)
{
   int r;
   lock (locker)
   {
      connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + path + ";Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=***********th");
      connection.Open();
      using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
      {
          command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, UserEmail, FirstName, LastName, FacebookID) VALUES (@Username, @UserEmail, @FirstName, @LastName,  @FacebookID)";
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", user.Email);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.UserName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", user.LName);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FacebookID", user.FacebookID);
          r = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       connection.Close();
       return r;
    }    
}
```

And I get the following information from the `facebook-sdk` login, so I simply need to execute that query in order to insert the data to the database? Is it right to use the sa account? Is inserting data into a database on an Android application done the same way it's done on a Windows application ? Until now I used the Microsoft Access and it was horribly simple and easy, but now as I moved on to SQL Server 2008 I'm kinda clueless.

Comment: Looks sensible - are you getting any errors?

Comment: Android uses Sqlite. Your code looks like C# meant for windows instead of Java code meant for Sqlite on android... Just google insert sqlite android and you will get a million results. But nothing will work unless you have the database ready to insert into.

Comment: @MuhammadA I don't want to use SQLite, SQLite is not a trustworthy database for high traffic databases as for what I read so I'm trying to switch it with an SQL Server.

Comment: :D good luck with that, android does not do SQL Server, only flat files are supported. The only way ever for you to use SQL Server would be to set up a ASP.NET webservice and call that from android over the web... but for huge traffic... that's a very bad idea. -- BTW. why would you ever want a high traffic DB on a mobile device!!! It will kill the battery in no time.

Comment: @MuhammadA And how do I do that exactly ? Also, I want a high traffic DB to store users, I expect a lot of users to log into the application and I need to store all of that data somewhere and I assumed SQLite won't be enough, won't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is not really a proper answer, but I did not want to keep making comments.

It seems to me that what you really want is a DB on a server and not in your android app, because if users are added in massive amounts then those users cannot be coming from the android OS itself, they must be coming from an external source, ie. the internet.

So if they are coming from the internet you need a central storage location, which is your server. An ASP.NET server hosting a SQL Server instance.

You will need a domain name, and a hosting solution. Use either MVC controllers or WebAPI to set up your website and/or services that interact with your SQL Server instance. I would recommend you use Entity Framework as well it would make your life a lot easier.

You have many hosts, AZURE is one, but its expensive. But the least it will cost you is something like £8 a month to host databases.

You would design your MVC website+services, or WebAPI (just services) using Visual Studio and use the settings the server host gives you to upload it.

Once the services are up then its a simple matter of making HTTP get/post calls to your server to get and set data in your database, and your android APP will act like a client.

I did this whole thing a week ago for a very simple scenario and it works well.

You would have to follow best practices on how to secure your web service, using some sort of authentication mechanism so only authorised users can access your data.

I hope the above gives you a general idea of how it can be accomplished. Its very high level and you will have to google each stage, but its pretty simple if you know some basics.

That's all I can say...